# Getting different values of particular variable from a file in UNIX

Tags: unix-shell, sed, xml, regular-expressions

I have a file which I'd like to parse to extract certain values from it. I don't know what command and syntax I should use (maybe `sed`?).

Below are 2 sample lines which I might expect to find in the file. What I need is the value of `name` (i.e `1234` and `xyz` respectively in the example) as well as the value of `jndiName`.

```
factories xmi:type="resources.url:URL" xmi:id="" name="1234" jndiName="xyz_aBC" 

factories xmi:type="resources.url:URL" xmi:id="URL_1323780357724" name="xyz" jndiName="abc"
```

If I use `sed`, how would I apply it in this situation?

Comment: Can you give us some valid xml to work with ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is [considered unwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to try and parse xml using standard unix utilities. I have used the [xml2](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) utility to parse xml files and then use grep/awk/sed etc to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is also a good alternative for parsing xml in shell if for religious reasons one can not use e.g. perl XML::Simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

By hinting that you might consider using regular expressions (sed) to parse an xml file you've uttered an incantation that will lead you [into the mouth of madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/462302)! [Please](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) [turn](http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) [back](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/)!